# Laravel Update With Relationships - Boa prática

Tags: laravel, relacionamento

Criei um Update para uma tabela Produtos que está relacionada com outra tabela que é o Artigo(product_info) desse produto.
Só que quando faço Update eu altero as informações do Produto, apago o artigo e volto a criar um artigo com o mesmo ou novo conteúdo. 
Está tudo a funcionar perfeitamente mas queria saber se é uma boa prática de programação ou se existe outro modo.

Basicamente é isto:

Controller:

```
$product = Product::find($id);
$product->display_name = Input::get('name_display');
$product->save();

$product->Product_info()->delete();

$product_info = New Product_info;
$product_info->name = Input::get('name');
$product_info->description = Input::get('description');
$product_info->Product()->associate($product);
$product_info->save();
```

Model: Produto.php

```
public function Product_info()
{
    return $this->hasOne('App\Product_info');
}
```

PS: Se não fui explicito avisem.

Comment: eu não deletaria `Produto_info()`, eu usaria a mesma instância e salvaria as novas informações, ou seja, *update*!

Comment: @VirgilioNovic O problema é que já tentei de várias formas e esta foi a única que não me deu problemas.

Comment: os dados da relação são obrigatórios? se existir product existe também product_info?

Comment: bom qualquer coisa poste o layout das tabelas se a resposta não der certo e o layout completo do model `Produto` e `Product_info`.!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Utilizaria a mesma instância, `$produto->Product_info()` se existir, se não, eu criaria o que você está fazendo.

```
$product = Product::find($id);
$product->display_name = Input::get('name_display');
$product->save();  

$product_info = $product->Product_info();
if (!$produto_info) 
{ 
    $product_info = New Product_info;
    $product_info->Product()->associate($product);
}
$product_info->name = Input::get('name');
$product_info->description = Input::get('description');
$product_info->save();
```

Se a relação for obrigatória na hora do cadastro, ou seja, é feito o registro de `product` e `product_info` pode usar um `update`:

```
$product = Product::find($id);
$product->display_name = Input::get('name_display');
$product->save();  

$product->Product_info()->update([
    'name' => Input::get('name'),
    'description' => Input::get('description')
]);
```

Comment: Obrigado, desconhecia a function update()! Acho que fica melhor dessa maneira!